# org.json.JSON.typeMismatch when converting a String

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to convert the following JSON in a Android app:

```
[
    {
        "patient_id": "16",
        "patient_firstname": "Ion",
        "patient_name": "Vasilescu",
        "location": "Cardiologie, Salon 4, Pat 2"
    },
    {
        "patient_id": "22",
        "patient_firstname": "Claudiu",
        "patient_name": "Popovici",
        "location": "Pneumologie, Salon 5, Pat 5"
    },
    {
        "patient_id": "15",
        "patient_firstname": "Monica",
        "patient_name": "Suciu",
        "location": "Cardiologie, Salon 4, Pat 2"
    }
]
```

I've read through simillar problems and answers but in my case I don't see any syntax problems. I've checked the JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it validated successfully.

My java code is as follows:

```
public JSONObject toJson(String jString){
    System.out.println("I've got"+jString+"*");

    try {
        return new JSONObject(jString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while converting to JSONObject");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Does anybody have advice on how to get rid of my error? Or on how to implement a better solution ? Thanks.

Comment: very nicely explained tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Post the full stack trace please.

Answer (score 4):

Replace JSONObject to JSONArray, since its an array!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting result as a JSon Array not JSon string so try to change slass

Your code:

```
public JSONObject toJson(String jString){
    System.out.println("I've got"+jString+"*");

    try {
        return new JSONObject(jString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while converting to JSONObject");
    }

    return null;
}
```

After modification:

```
public JSONObject toJson(String jString){
    System.out.println("I've got"+jString+"*");

    try {
        return new JSONArray(jString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while converting to JSONObject");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Look at your code you are returning JSONArray but method retun type is JSONObject?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) your json contain only `JsonArray` List so just convert your `String` to `JSONArray`  instead of `JSONObject` as:

```
public JSONArray toJson(String jString){
    System.out.println("I've got"+jString+"*");

    try {
        return new JSONArray(jString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while converting to JSONArray");
    }

    return null;
}
```